Apply args/variables renaming to the whole function code [radare2]
I stuck with a problem in Radare2: when I rename function arguments, their names change only in the args list.
Before:
│ ; arg int32_t arg3 @ rdx
│ ; arg int32_t arg4 @ rcx

Command:
afvr rdx count int
afvr rcx ptr void*

Args list:
│ ; arg int count @ rdx
│ ; arg void* ptr @ rcx

In the assembly code of the function, however, nothing changes - arguments have the same names as before renaming:
...
cmp edx, 0x4a                         ; 'J' ; 74 ; arg3
...
cmp ecx, 0x4a                         ; 'J' ; 74 ; arg4
...

Could you tell me, how can I apply argument name changes to the whole function code?
Thank you!

Versions:
radare2 5.9.3 0 @ linux-x86-64
birth: git.5.9.3 2024-07-17__21:49:23
commit: 5.9.3
options: gpl release -O? cs:5 cl:2 make

